# Django unique_together not preventing duplicates

Tags: python, django

I am clearly not understanding how to do this correctly, can someone set me straight.  Here is the model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
   teamID=models.CharField(max_length=255) #this will be generated on the iPad
   name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
   slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50) 
   teamNumber=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   checkIn=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
   totalScore=models.IntegerField(max_length=6) 

   class Meta:
       unique_together = ("teamID", "name", "slug", "teamNumber", "totalScore")
```

If I submit twice in a row it saves all of it. Yikes!!!

Comment: Also there is a model which uses this model as a FK, I wonder if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: This is enforced at the database level - did you remember to run `python manage.py syncdb` after adding the `unique_together` field?

Comment: well, I ran a migration... let me try just a plain 'ol sync

Comment: Hmm, it was worth a shot. What version of Django are you using?

Comment: It won't matter if you run syncdb _again_, that will not update the database schema. Use south for migrations, or drop and re-create the table.

Comment: I am using South. Django 1.3.1. I am now trying adding unique_together to all the child tables.

Comment: Still nothing. Is it the fact that I have a datetime in there? Is there a way to stop an entry even if the datetime is different? Perhaps I need to handle this in the view...

Comment: Did you check that your `unique_together` was really applied to your DB after the migration?

Comment: Stop, guys. Plain `syncdb` can't to alter a table or create any keys.

Comment: If you are using MySQL, then try to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE 'table_name';` in the `dbshell`, and then post it's output here.

Comment: By the way. Probably, it is not very good idea to create such huge uniq keys :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the proper nested-tuple syntax `((foo,bar),)` instead of just `(foo, bar)`?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: I have... to no avail, I must just be missing something simple here

Comment: OK, here is the issue, if I enter the data in the admin Django *will* prevent duplicate entries, but the weird little mobile app that is sending my Django app data cannot do any validation like Django admin, nor can it receive a message from my Django app. I just need Django not write this data at all. I know, this is a strange use case.

Comment: OK,so now I decided to go back to the app and send a validation error msg. I think this will work now. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Actually, nested tuple syntax isn't needed. Perhaps it was at the time?

Comment: Idk @mlissner but in django 2.2, I just resolved that problem with that...

Say I wonder why it started now, Single tuple used to work till in this new model

Answer (score 27):

As aganders3 mentions the constraint is enforced at the database level; I assume though that you are using a database like SQLite that doesn't support this kind of constraint.

The reason that it all works as expected through the admin is that it is doing the uniqueness check itself (it doesn't rely strictly on the database to signal constraint violations).

You can switch to a database engine that supports this kind of uniqueness constraint (either MySQL or Postgres would work) or you could look at adding the check in using signals: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1628/

Answer (score 8):

Yes the paremeter unique_together receives as input a tuple of tuples, I have not tested tuples of more than two elements but it should work

for your example:

```
unique_together = (("teamID", "name"), ("slug", "teamNumber"))
```

or:

```
unique_together = (("teamID", "name", "slug", "teamNumber", "totalScore"))
```

Comment: Your second example lacks the trailing comma required in a 1-element tuple, effectively making it a tuple with a length of 4 with extra-do-nothing-parens. It works, but it does b/c Django doesn't require a tuple of tuples if there's only 1 unique grouping. My issue was solved making sure the `unique_together` is under the Meta class, not the model. D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

I found this approach helpful without adding any unnecessary fields

```
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='request_list', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requested_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    request_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Checking for duplicate requests
        try:
            request = Request.objects.get(user=self.user, requested_user=self.requested_user)
            raise ValidationError('Duplicate Value', code='invalid')
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        # Checking for reversed duplicate requests
        try:
            request_new = Request.objects.get(requested_user=self.user, user=self.requested_user)
            raise ValidationError('Duplicate Value', code='invalid')
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + '------>' + self.requested_user.username
```

Comment: why such trouble while unique_together does it all?